# How do I prevent web service from auto generating properties from fields in reference.cs

Tags: c#, web-services, reflection

I've got an issue where some code in an old win forms app that is using reflection on an object from a web service to get a list of fields.  The reflection is calling GetFields().  In my data object in the web service I have fields defined as such:

```
public string PropertyAddress1;
public string PropertyAddress2;
public string PropertyCity;
public string PropertyCounty;
public string PropertyState;
```

In the current version of reference.cs that exists in the win forms app the fields look like so.

```
public string PropertyAddress1;
public string PropertyAddress2;
public string PropertyCity;
public string PropertyCounty;
public string PropertyState;
```

The same right?

Well, I went in to the web service's class and added another field. I then went into the win forms app, right clicked and hit update web reference.  When the code is regenerated the reference.cs looks like this:

```
private string propertyAddress1Field;
private string propertyAddress2Field;
private string propertyCityField;
private string propertyCountyField;
private string propertyStateField;

   public string PropertyAddress1 {
        get {
            return this.propertyAddress1Field;
        }
        set {
            this.propertyAddress1Field = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string PropertyAddress2 {
        get {
            return this.propertyAddress2Field;
        }
        set {
            this.propertyAddress2Field = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string PropertyCity {
        get {
            return this.propertyCityField;
        }
        set {
            this.propertyCityField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string PropertyCounty {
        get {
            return this.propertyCountyField;
        }
        set {
            this.propertyCountyField = value;
        }
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    public string PropertyState {
        get {
            return this.propertyStateField;
        }
        set {
            this.propertyStateField = value;
        }
    }
```

This is throwing off the behavior of existing code because GetFields() is no longer returning anything.  I know I could swap it to GetProperties() but the class already has properties defined that I do not want returned back in the result set. I would like the reference .cs to generate fields as fields and properties as properties instead of converting fields to properties.  Is there any way I can put some data annotations or some other sort of flag that prevents this behavior in the auto generated reference.cs for fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try manually updating the reference.cs file to replace the properties with fields.  I'd be willing to bet that's what the previous authors did if the reference isn't already somehow configured to use fields instead of properties.

Comment: I have a feeling that is what happened too.  I had also heard that there were earlier versions of .net or visual studio that the auto generator engine may have not automatically converted fields to properties and I was hoping there was a setting that could control this.